# Proof verification: Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem fails in $\ell^2$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

> Find a bounded sequence in the sequence space $\ell^2$ such that it has no convergent subsequence.

I think the sequence $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ works where $e_1=(1,0,...)$, $e_2=(0,1,0,...)$, ....

I would be glad if you could check my attempt.

**Attempt.** 
To get a contradiction, suppose it has a subsequence $\{e_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ that converges to some point $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ in $\ell^2$. Then, we have
$$0=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|e_{n_k}-x\|_2=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2\right)-x_{n_k}^2+(1-x_{n_k})^2  \right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1-2x_{n_k}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2\right)$$
which implies that 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=\frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2}{2}>0$$
So $x\notin\ell^2$, contradiction.

Comment: It has no Cauchy subsequence because $n\ne m\implies \|e_n-e_m\|=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Correct.... You can also see  that for every $x\in l^2,$ there is at most one $n$ such that $e_n$ belongs to the open ball $B(x, 1/\sqrt 2).$  If a subsequence of $(e_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converged to $x\in l^2$ then $\{n: e_n\in B(x,1/\sqrt 2)\}$ would have to be an infinite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems alright. The ${e_n}_k$ notation weirds me out, but that’s a small detail.

Here’s another solution. You could simply say that for all $i$, if $x_i\neq0$, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}||e_k-x||_2\geq\lim_{k\to\infty}\left({e_k}_i-x_i\right)^2=x_i^2>0,$$ so that the limit, if it exists, is the null vector. But in that case, the limit would be $1$, contradiction.